# How to make address withdraw full amount in wallet or none

Tags: solidity, wallets, smart-contract-wallets

I'm doing a project where I want to make a banknote for an etherum, but the main problem is I want the user to access the hidden private key of ethereum wallet, access it and withdraw the full amount of ether inside the address, but not in parts

for example, I have a 0.1 ether banknote, I want to transfer it to my personal wallet, I will access the wallet of the banknote where the 0.1 ether is present, but I should withdraw whole 0.1 ether from the wallet, withdrawing 0.04 or in parts would not be allowed.

Is there any approach to do this?

Comment: you can impose that the withdrawl is limited to the entire amount. please post some of your code for more clearence.

Comment: Actually I have not developed any code for it, I just want user to access wallet by metamask and withdraw right from there

Comment: if he has access to the private key he can withdraw whatever he decide. Which is to say ,you can't do it. you can make a token

Comment: if you don't want to write a contract then google about "custodial wallet". You will have to hold the private key and do all transactions on the behalf of the user. But this is very risky business and you will be constantly receiving hackers attempts to steal funds

Comment: @Nulik no this is all about decentralisation, I don't want it centralised

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин you are right, but say u have a $10 banknote and want to purchase a $5 item, do you just rip off half of $10 banknote or give shopkeeper whole $10 note and take change back. This is a point. If I would do a straightforward approach then what would be difference between paper wallet and my project??

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин token creation would be my last option, my concern is whether there is any way to do this thing in main etherum.

Comment: but you don't have a banknote

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин  yes, I have... I am designing a physical banknote for Ethereum...

Comment: he will just import address to a wallet without of care of what you wanna haha